# Vagrant Private Network IPs not working, but DHCP does

Tags: mac, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a vagrant config file with three VMs configured in it. All are identical except on has a static IP and the other two are on DHCP. The two which are assigned IPs by DHCP can talk to each other without any issues, but the one with a static IP cannot be contacted by the others.

In other words ping `client0` -> `client1` works

ping `client1` -> `client0` works

ping `client1` -> `server` does not

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "provision/cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "python"
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/python-modules.py"

  config.vm.define :server do |server|
    server.vm.hostname = "server"
    server.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.28.128.2"
  end

  config.vm.define :client0 do |client0|
    client0.vm.hostname = "client0"
    client0.vm.network :private_network, type: :dhcp
  end

  config.vm.define :client1 do |client1|
    client1.vm.hostname = "client1"
    client1.vm.network :private_network, type: :dhcp
  end
end
```

Any ideas how I can get the `server` machine to be contactable by the others on a static IP? I'm using the virtualbox providor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After extensive research and experimentation it appears that Vagrant was assigning each VM to a different submask, hence them not being able to connect to each other. In effect, they were all on different networks.

It turns out you can, however, override this. To do so, simply configure the netmask for one as shown below.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "provision/cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "python"
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/python-modules.py"

  config.vm.define :server do |server|
    server.vm.hostname = "server"
    server.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.28.128.2", :netmask => "255.255.0.0"
  end

  config.vm.define :client0 do |client0|
    client0.vm.hostname = "client0"
    client0.vm.network :private_network, type: :dhcp, :netmask => "255.255.0.0"
  end

  config.vm.define :client1 do |client1|
    client1.vm.hostname = "client1"
    client1.vm.network :private_network, type: :dhcp, :netmask => "255.255.0.0"
  end
end
```

At this time I am unsure as to whether you can override the netmask for all on the global config, while maintaining some VMs with DHCP and other with a static IP. I'll experiment with that once I'm am back on a more powerful machine so destroying and creating the VM each time is faster.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue I had where I couldn't ssh between guests on OSX.

Comment: Using Vagrant 1.9.7, OSX 10.12.6, VirtualBox 5.1.24r117012, I had this same issue - could not connect between guests. The netmask seemed to work, even with private IPs. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You could also done something like below, if you provisioning multiple VM's with DHCP. In optional VM section you can mention/name multiple VM's you required.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

DOMAIN = '.example.com'
PUPPETMASTER_HOSTNAME = 'puppet' + DOMAIN

#Requires box with puppetlabs repo setup, but puppet not installed
DEFAULT_BOX = 'precise64'
DEFAULT_BOX_URL = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box'

REQUIRED_HOSTS = [
  'puppetdb',
  'puppetdb-postgres'
]

OPTIONAL_HOSTS = [
  'ldap01',
  'ldap02'

]

HOSTS = REQUIRED_HOSTS + OPTIONAL_HOSTS

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  #VBox config to avoid mac address collisions
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natnet1', '10.200/16']
    #vb.gui = true
  end

  config.vm.box = DEFAULT_BOX
  config.vm.box_url = DEFAULT_BOX_URL

  #Add network interface
  config.vm.network :private_network, :type => :dhcp, :netmask => '255.255.0.0'

  #Defines puppet master
  config.vm.define :puppet_master do |puppetmaster|
    puppetmaster.vm.hostname = PUPPETMASTER_HOSTNAME
    puppetmaster.vm.synced_folder '../puppet/', '/vagrant_sync/puppet', :create => true
    puppetmaster.vm.provision :shell, :path => 'scripts/bootstrap_puppetmaster.sh'
  end

  HOSTS.each do |host_name, opts|
    config.vm.define host_name do |box|
      fqdn = host_name + DOMAIN

      box.vm.hostname = fqdn
      box.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'yum install -y puppet'
      box.vm.provision :puppet_server do |puppet|
        puppet.puppet_server = PUPPETMASTER_HOSTNAME
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent solution, thanks for sharing this.  I'll have to update my local configuration file now, this is a much cleaner solution when multiple identical client are required for testing. Thanks!